# TYPO3-extension webkitpdf (wkhtml2pdf) can't use login-secured pages (fe_users)

Tags: typo3, wkhtmltopdf, typoscript, typo3-extensions

I'm using webkitpdf to generate PDFs out of TYPO3-pages. This works like a charm - except with pages which are behind an fe_users-Login.

The webkitpdf implements wkhtml2pdf which works not under the scope of the TYPO3-rights-and-login-system but directly on the server as a binary. It calls the pages (which should be converted to PDFs) from the outside like a not-logged-in-browser.

Does anyone have an idea how this issue could be solved? (No solution needed, only an idea to approach the issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--cookie` option in wkhtmltopdf to pass the cookie of a logged in user.

Comment: Thank you, this was the right direction, although it's very complex to make it work: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/8433